# Get groupposition of listview by String attached to it (android)

Tags: android, android-listview

I have listview with elements and i'm trying to implement basic search from that listview.

This function creates it's elements:

```
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<namesmails.size();i = i+2) {
        //namesmails[0] == name && namesmails[1] == phone && namesmails[2] == email
        String name = namesmails.get(i);
        String mail = namesmails.get(i + 1);
        String phone = returnNumber(namesphones,name);
        listDataHeader.add(name);
        List<String> currentName = new ArrayList<String>();
        currentName.add(phone);
        currentName.add(mail);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), currentName);
        counter += 1;
    }
```

Now on search i have query + i know that the input was successful (the name exists in the list, but i don't know how to access it).

```
if (namesmails.contains(query)){
    //I want to get the position of queryed name to expand-it. Currently
    //i've set static number (20) to expand and select.
    expListView.expandGroup(20)
    expListView.setSelection(20);
}
```

How could i access the Expandable ListView by name added to it so i could expand it and set it selected?

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a friend who apparently isn't an user of this site but if anyone in future needs help, this is one of the solutions possible. This is probably not the only solution out there (since there's probably a way to access children directly with name) but i came up with a sort of work-around.

I created an additional ArrayList called onlynames in the beginning of my class, setting it as a global variable.

In the method:

```
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<namesmails.size();i = i+2) {
    //namesmails[0] == name && namesmails[1] == phone && namesmails[2] == email
    String name = namesmails.get(i);
    String mail = namesmails.get(i + 1);
    String phone = returnNumber(namesphones,name);
    namesonly.add(name);
    listDataHeader.add(name);
    List<String> currentName = new ArrayList<String>();
    currentName.add(phone);
    currentName.add(mail);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(counter), currentName);
    counter += 1;
}
```

I added namesonly.add(name): Now namesonly has same position on names as listDataHeader so i can just call it out:

```
if (namesmails.contains(query)){
    int el = namesonly.indexOf(query);
    expListView.expandGroup(el)
    expListView.setSelection(el);
}
```

And this worked :).